# Initial Velocity For Orbital (Gravity) Slingshot At Hit Moving Target

Tags: gravity, orbital-motion, planets

In this problem we have three masses, Mass A is on the left side of the sun Mass B is the sun, and Mass C is on the right side of the sun. I want to calculate the initial velocity of Mass A to hit Mass C, while Mass C is moving away from the sun. Below is a diagram:

[image]

I want to know what equation to use to solve this, knowing the initial velocity of Mass C 10000 m/s. Mass A should hit Mass C on the right side of the sun, following an elliptical orbit.

Similar Question: [Calculate Initial Velocity For Orbital (Gravity) Slingshot](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/151244/calculate-initial-velocity-for-orbital-gravity-slingshot)

Comment: Related by OP: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/151244/calculate-initial-velocity-for-orbital-gravity-slingshot

Answer (score 2):

This basically is a specific case of [Lambert's problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert%27s_problem). I will cover the maths involved solving the problem in your case.

When looking at the velocity of mass C, 10000 m/s radial outwards relative to the sun, it can be noted that its movement therefore will basically be one dimensional along the radial direction. This means that its [angular moment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specific_relative_angular_momentum) is zero and therefore its [eccentricity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital_eccentricity) has to be one. When comparing its velocity to [escape velocity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_velocity) it can be concluded that mass C does not have an escape trajectory, namely 
$$
\sqrt{\frac{2GM_{sun}}{r_C}} \approx 54762\ m/s,
$$
and thus its trajectory will be a radial elliptic trajectory with a semi-major axis of
$$
a = \frac{\mu r}{2\mu-v^2r},
$$
a periapsis of zero and thus an apoapsis of twice the semi-major axis.

As stated in the question, mass A will have an elliptical orbit. For this I will assume that its periapsis and apoapsis would be located along the same line as the movement of mass C. This will allow you to easily calculate the time it will take mass A to travel from periapsis to apoapsis, or from periapsis to apoapsis, depending on whether the radius of the point of collision with C would be bigger or smaller than 100 Gm. In both cases this will result in half the [orbital period](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital_period#Calculation):
$$
\frac{T_A}{2} = \pi \sqrt{\frac{a^3}{\mu}},
$$
where $a$ is the semi-major axis of the orbit of mass A and $\mu$ the gravitational parameter of the sun.

To solve this problem you basically want to find the radius of the collision, such that mass A and C will take the same amount of time to get there. The time it will takes mass C to reach its apoapsis will always be shorter than that of mass A, since mass C will always have a periapsis smaller than that of A and thus have a shorter orbital period. Thus the collision will happen when mass C has passed its apoapsis and is falling back towards the sun. There is no analytical solution for its radius as a function of time, however you can calculate the time its takes as a function of its radius by using an adapted formulation of [Kepler's equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler%27s_equation),

$$
t_C(r) = \sqrt{\frac{a^3}{\mu}} \left(2\tan^{-1}{\sqrt{\frac{r-a(1-e)}{a(1+e)-r}}}-\sqrt{e^2-\left(1-\frac{r}{a}\right)^2}\right)
$$
where $t(r)$ is the time since periapsis passage. But keep in mind that this equation does not know whether you have passed your apoapsis. As stated above, C has passed apoapsis, so the effective time, $t_{C,eff}$, it will take to reach the radius of collision, $r_{col}$, would be
$$
t_{C,eff} = T_C-t_C(r_C)-t_C(r_{col})
$$
where $T_C$ is the orbital period of mass C. The trajectory of C will probably not be periodic, since its periapsis is zero, but for the maths it still gives a time scale for when you only cover a part of the orbit where $r\neq 0$.

To solve the problem you have to find $r_{col}$, such that $t_{C,eff}=\frac{T_A}{2}$, using that the semi-major axis of A is equal to the average of its initial radius and $r_{col}$. Since this equation will contain both algebraic and transcendental functions it will not be possible to solve it analytically, so you probably will have to use a numeric method to approximate the solution. From this $r_{col}$ and your previous question you can easily calculate the required velocity of A such that its apoapsis/periapsis would be at $r_{col}$.

---

In response to the comment of Melle Sterk, I will also include the mathematics involved when finding the solutions which might not involve locations of the periapsis/apoapsis along the same line as the movement of mass C. In the general case there will be a solution for every value for $r_{col}$, however the trajectory of A might become hyperbolic. For this the equation for the travel time of A will have to be changed into something similar to that of C, but instead of travel time as a function of $r$, I will use the travel time as a function of the [true anomaly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/True_anomaly), $\theta$, since it is a given that the angle between initial position of A and collision will always be $\pi$ radians (or 180°).

$$
t_A(\theta)=\sqrt{\frac{a^3}{\mu}}\left(2\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{1-e^2}\tan{\frac{\theta}{2}}}{1+e}\right)-\frac{e\sqrt{1-e^2}\sin{\theta}}{1+e\cos{\theta}}\right)
$$

The variable you have to solve for this time is the start true anomaly of A, $\theta_{A}$. From this the eccentricity and semi-major axis of the orbit of A have to be expressed into $\theta_{A}$ and can be found by using the constrains that the initial position is at the radius $r_A$ and the final position is at the radius $r_{col}$. By using the equation for the [radius as a function of the true anomaly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/True_anomaly#Radius_from_true_anomaly) and some substitution the following equations for the eccentricity and semi-major axis can be obtained.

$$
a = r_A r_{col} \frac{\left(\cos{(\theta_A)}-\cos{(\theta_A+\pi)}\right) - \left(r_A\cos{(\theta_A)}-r_{col}\cos{(\theta_A+\pi)}\right)}{\left(r_A\cos{(\theta_A)}-r_{col}\cos{(\theta_A+\pi)}\right)^2-\left(r_A-r_{col}\right)^2}
$$

$$
e = \frac{r_{col} - r_A}{r_A\cos{(\theta_A)}-r_{col}\cos{(\theta_A+\pi)}}
$$

If you would substitute these equations for the eccentricity and semi-major axis into the equation for the travel time of A since periapsis passage, you can find $\theta_{A}$ by solving:

$$
t_A(\theta_A+\pi)-t_A(\theta_A) = t_{C,eff}(r_{col})
$$

You can also change $t_{C,eff}$ such that mass C does not pass by apoapsis, however I suspect that the trajectory for A will then always be hyperbolic.

Comment: Is it possible to speed up the approach by burning in a different direction then prograde

Comment: @MelleSterk yes, in that case there will be a solution for every $r_{col}$, but will have different travel times (however the trajectory of A might become hyperbolic). For this you have the change to way you calculate the travel time of A. I will update my answer to include this as well.

Answer (score 0):

Oke this [link](http://www.bogan.ca/orbits/kepler/orbteqtn.html) is a nice reference sheet for elliptical orbits.
we are interested in two things

- the speed at perihelion
- The time it will take to reach aphelion

[image]

The initial velocity is what OP wants to now.
The time it will take to reach aphelion will be compared with the position at time t of object C

So lets call $r_c(t)$ the distance of Object C to the Sun at time t

$$ - \frac{G M m}{r_c^2} = \frac{M}{M+m} m \ddot r_c $$

$$
t = 4\pi (\frac{(r_{b,i}+r_b(t))^3}{2^3\mu})^{\frac{1}{2}}
$$
Solving the above equation is hard because you need to solve
$ r_c(t)=r_b(t) $ for $t$ .

Once you have a $t$ you ca plug it in the below equation to find your init velocity

$$
v_{b,i}^2 = \mu(2/r_{b,i} - \frac{2}{r_{b,i}+r_b(t)}) $$

Comment: How do I use that to solve the problem above?

Comment: @AlexPelletier it is very hard to solve this equation by hand I suggest you look at something like Wolfram alpha/mathematicato solve this for you.